# Summarise spent time in custom queries

Tags: ruby, redmine

Is it possible to have a summary amount on "Spent time" field in custom queries?

Any plugin available for that or I should modify the code?

Comment: we need an exam of what you're trying to do.  Given X input I need Y output.

Comment: Can you please be clear and provide some example.

Comment: I would like to see the total amount of spent time for all the issues after the filtering. Something like this: https://qsnapnet.com/snaps/adl99aivs8257b9